# Deleting nodes of a Binary Tree

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have made a binary tree in c++ where nodes are created with the new operator so I wanted to make a clear function that would delete all the nodes. The function looks like this:

```
void deleteNodes(Node* node) {
    if (node == nullptr) {
        return;
    }
        
    //std::cout << "running - " << node->data << std::endl;
    deleteNodes(node->left);
    deleteNodes(node->right);
    //std::cout << "deleting - " << node->data << std::endl;
    delete node;
    //std::cout << "deleted" << std::endl;
}
```

It gives me this error: "Exception thrown: read access violation. node was 0xDDDDDDDD."

When I wanted to see how it would print in the console with cout uncommented it prints that in the console:

```
running - 4
running - 3
deleting - 3
deleted
running - 5
running - 8
deleting - 8
deleted
deleting - 5
deleted
deleting - 4
deleted
running - -572662307
```

It looks like the node at the end in the console is nullptr but there is a condition in the beginning which should return if the node is nullptr so I'm not sure what's wrong here.

The data in the binary tree is 4,3,5,8 (left Node is smaller, right Node greater).

Comment: are you sure you populate the tree properly?

Comment: When im doing in order traversal it shows the elements properly so I assume its populated properly.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code you are showing. The problem is most likely in the code you have not shown. Follow the tips in [mre]

Comment: i would recomend you to try to populate it manually and then run the code

Comment: Changing the root pointer to null after calling the deleteNodes function fixed the problem, so I guess it was undefined behaviour from the Node pointer which was deleted but not set to null. Still I don't why it shows running at the end if there are no more calls to the function. Doesn't happen if I set root to null after calling the function.